# How to get the values of all textfields in add/remove textfields and form JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using a plugin to duplicate textfields on add and remove buttons. Now, after getting the fields added and removed, I want to form JSON out of all the textfields and POST it on submit.

Below is the code -

```
$(function () {

    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt_' + i + '" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/11008/) can be referred to.
I want to get the values of all textfields and form JSON.

Comment: Start by updating to a current version of jQuery, and use `on` instead of `live`. It's not going to solve your problem, but using a five year old version of jQuery sure isn't going to help either.

Comment: @adeneo You mean it does not help in creating JSON

Comment: How do you want your JSON to be structured? Do you want the input name as keys?

Comment: @PatrickQ I can give you an example `{"welcomesList":["Thanks for calling us","Please give the list"]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the input fields, grab their values, and push them through `JSON.stringify` to create your desired JSON.

```
function serializeAndPost() {
    var values = [];
    $( '#p_scents input[id^=p_scnt_]' ).each( function ( index, element ) {
        values.push( element.value );
    } );
    var json = JSON.stringify( { "welcomesList": values } );

    // Do your POSTing here
}
```

Updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/11019/

Comment: What you have done is right, but I get a different JSOn and not the one I posted above for PAtrickQ

Comment: I can give you an example `{"welcomesList":["Thanks for calling us","Please give the list"]}`

Comment: So, you'd basically like the array to be filled with only the values from the input fields? Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/11015/

Comment: It would be great if you put at least the relevant JS in the answer itself just in case (heaven forbid) something ever happens to jsfiddle.

Comment: @Wedvich What you have done is for whole form. If I have to do it for only inputfields(say p_scents). How I should do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution as I am building a string rather than an JSON object but here is my solution:

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"></input>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {

    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt_' + i + '" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var str = [];
        $.each($('input[type=text]'), function(i, val) {
            var el = $(this);
            str.push('"' + el.attr("id") + '":"' + el.val() +'"');
        });
        var json_string = "{" + str + "}";
    });
});
```